# VS Code doesn't see 'python' and 'pip', but cmd does. At the same time, neither cmd nor VS Code can see the virtual env folder

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm creating a web page in Flask Python using VS Code, and there's a problem. Let's start by creating a virtual environment folder in VS Code:

`python -m venv auth`

After that, the auth folder appears in the development environment. And then the funniest,
I write command in cmd:

`auth\Scripts\activate.bat`

To which cmd responds that 'auth' does not exist
Perhaps this should have been done from the VS Code terminal, but there ... there is no Python (although it is there in cmd), and there is no pip (although it is on the command line).

Tell me, please, who had the same problem?
And in general, if it is important, I do not highlight the code from the word at all.

Yes, and I installed python 3.9 because I thought that the problem was in the version, removed 3.1, left 3.9 and 3.1 at the same time, removed 3.9 and left 3.1

Answer (score 0):

I think you didn't choose the correct interpreter.

After you creating the virtual environment, you have to use shortcuts "Ctrl+Shift+P" and type "Python: Select Interpreter" to choose the virtual interpreter.

Read [VsCode-Python-Environment](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_using-the-create-environment-command) for more details.